# JS: How to randomize an array in a loop yet only allow each value to be selected once?

Tags: javascript

That's a mouthful.

Basically I have a loop and am assigning a unique number between 1 & 4 to an array value. This loop runs 4 times and each time there should be one less choice due to already being used in the previous cycle.

Here is a js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jtree5757/mh3okwaj/

And here is some code:

```
var employee_name = document.getElementsByClassName("employee-name");
var masterArray = [];

var numbersArr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var random = numbersArr.splice(Math.random()*numbersArr.length,1)[0];

for(i=0; i < employee_name.length; i++){
    masterArray.push({
        name: employee_name[i].innerText,
        shift: random
    });
}
```

This outputs the same number for each cycle of the loop. Not sure where to go on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var random = numbersArr.splice(Math.random()*numbersArr.length,1)[0];
```

This piece of code should be in your `for` loop. That way on each iteration new value will be generated.

You can see the updated [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mh3okwaj/1/)

Comment: thanks for reposting your answer and explanation. It works now!